# How can I monitor node-cron queued jobs?

Tags: node.js, cron, node-cron

I recently started using node-cron as a job scheduler. I have a lot of jobs that are being queued.

Is there a way I can monitor them using a visual tool (something like Agendash does for Agenda)?

Or how would you monitor and debug jobs in general? (trying to find some best-practices)